# Mongodb aggregate by day and delete duplicate value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to clean a huge database.

Sample DB :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59fc5249d5ab401d99f3de7f"),
  "addedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-03T11:26:01.744Z"),
  "__v" : 0,
  "check" : 17602,
  "lastCheck" : ISODate("2018-04-05T11:47:00.609Z"),
  "tracking" : [
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:17:20.861Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a0060e00f3c330012bafe39"),
      "rank" : 2395,
  }, 
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:22:31.254Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a0062170f3c330012bafe77"),
      "rank" : 2395,
  }, 
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:27:40.551Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a00634c0f3c330012bafebe"),
      "rank" : 2379,
  }, 
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:32:41.084Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a0064790f3c330012baff03"),
      "rank" : 2395,
  }, 
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:37:51.012Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a0065af0f3c330012baff32"),
      "rank" : 2379,
  }, 
  {
  "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-07T13:37:51.012Z"),
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a0065af0f3c330012baff34"),
  "rank" : 2379,
  }]
}
```

I have a lot of duplicate value but I need to clean only by day.
To obtain this for example :

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59fc5249d5ab401d99f3de7f"),
  "addedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-03T11:26:01.744Z"),
  "__v" : 0,
  "check" : 17602,
  "lastCheck" : ISODate("2018-04-05T11:47:00.609Z"),
  "tracking" : [
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:17:20.861Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a0060e00f3c330012bafe39"),
      "rank" : 2395,
  }, 
  {
      "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-06T13:27:40.551Z"),
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a00634c0f3c330012bafebe"),
      "rank" : 2379,
  }, 
  {
  "timeCheck" : ISODate("2017-11-07T13:37:51.012Z"),
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a0065af0f3c330012baff34"),
  "rank" : 2379,
  }]
}
```

How can I aggregate by day and after delete last value duplicate?
I need to keep the values per day even if they are identical with another day.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation framework cannot update data at this stage. However, you can use the following aggregation pipeline in order to get the desired output and then use e.g. a [bulk replace](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#replaceone) to update all your documents:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$tracking" // flatten the "tracking" array into separate documents
}, {
    $sort: {
        "tracking.timeCheck": 1 // sort by timeCheck to allow us to use the $first operator in the next stage reliably
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {  // group by
            "_id": "$_id", // "_id" and 
            "rank": "$tracking.rank", // "rank" and
            "date": { // the "date" part of the "timeCheck" field
                $dateFromParts : {
                    year: { $year: "$tracking.timeCheck" },
                    month:  { $month: "$tracking.timeCheck" },
                    day: { $dayOfWeek: "$tracking.timeCheck" }
                }
            }
        },
        "doc": { $first: "$$ROOT" } // only keep the first document per group
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "doc.tracking.timeCheck": 1 // restore ascending sort order - may or may not be needed...
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id._id", // merge everything again per "_id"
        "addedAt": { $first: "$doc.addedAt" },
        "__v": { $first: "$doc.__v" },
        "check": { $first: "$doc.check" },
        "lastCheck": { $first: "$doc.lastCheck" },
        "tracking": { $push: "$doc.tracking" } // in order to join the tracking values into an array again
    }
})
```

Comment: This might exactly be the nearest solution for OP's question.

Comment: @dnickless thanks for your reply but I need keep also by day. I have try to add "timeCheck": "$tracking.timeCheck" in the first $group but he return all subdocuments

Comment: Not sure I understand... Can you update your question or give me an example, please?

Comment: I have uppdate my question with one subdocument in other day